# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and limit

Tags: calculus

I've been reading through a paper and my question has essentially came down to this:

Let

$f(\beta) \to M$ as $ \beta \to 0$ and $f(\alpha) \to 0$ as $\alpha \to \infty.$ Prove that $M=-\int_{0}^\infty f'(x)dx$. I wanted to check this before going any further. It is probably trivial but here is my attempt.

My attempt:

$$M=\lim_{\beta \to 0}f(\beta)$$
$$M=\lim_{\beta \to 0 , \alpha \to \infty}\left[f(\beta)- f(\alpha)\right]$$
$$M=-\lim_{\beta \to 0,\alpha \to \infty}\left[\int_\beta^\alpha f'(s)dx\right]$$
$$M=-\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} f'(x)dx$$
as required.

Comment: Just check your signs, there is a minor mistake. In the formulation of the problem also, $M$ should not have that minus sign.

Comment: Ahh, caught it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right , just the signs are here and there.Rest is fine

Answer (score 1):

Right.

Just be aware of the fact that this last notation is a limit, maybe not an integral unlike the notation could suggest. Hence, usual results on generalized integrals can be unsuited for it.